# Export SQL data from database to Excel using PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, mysqli, phpexcel

I am trying to export data from my database to Excel using PHPExcel. I used the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28449860/using-phpexcel-to-export-mysql-to-excel). Edited mysql to mysqli and changed the extension to xlsx format. But when I want to open the file I get the following error (I translated it into English so sorry for my bad English if it isn't right)

> The file rapportage 29-05-2017.xlsx can't be opened because the file format or file extension is not valid. Check if the file isn't damaged and if the file extension matches with the format of the file.

This is the code I copied and changed:

```
<?php
require 'database.php';
require '../Classes/PHPExcel.php';

if (isset($_POST['exporteer'])) {

    $a = $_POST['organisatie_naam'];
    $b = $_POST['begin_datum'];
    $c = $_POST['eind_datum'];
    $datum = date("d-m-Y");

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE organisatie_naam = '$a' AND (registratie_aansluit_datum BETWEEN '$b' AND '$c'";

    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    $rowCount = 1;

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $row['registratie_id']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $row['registratie_soort']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $row['organisatie_naam']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $row['apparaat_naam']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $row['client_naam']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$rowCount, $row['dienst_naam']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$rowCount, $row['functie_naam']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$rowCount, $row['kosten_soort']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$rowCount, $row['status_naam']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$rowCount, $row['registratie_aansluit_datum']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$rowCount, $row['registratie_afsluit_datum']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$rowCount, $row['registratie_omschr']);
        $rowCount++;
        pr($objPHPExcel);
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-   officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="rapportage ' . $datum . '.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    header("Location: ../rapportage.php");
}
?>
```

Anyone who knows if I maybe missed something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what does `pr($objPHPExcel);` do?

Comment: And those spaces in the Content-Type header won't help either

Comment: Plus headers to redirect after the output has been sent to the browser should give warnings, that are probably being injected into the output and breaking it

Comment: I removed those spaces, that was a mistake. And also removed the header after the output. But I still get this warning.. @MarkBaker

Comment: Then open the file in a text editor. Look for any leading/trailing whitespace characters, or any plaintext PHP messages/warnings

Comment: And again, what does `pr($objPHPExcel)` do?

Comment: @MarkBaker I checked the code from the one I got the code from and pr() does actually nothing. I also removed the duplicate '$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();'. After that I opened the file in a text editor and saw that my query missed a ')' at the end. Now it works, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
require('../phpexcel/PHPExcel.php');

require('../phpexcel/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5.php');

$filename = 'userReport'; //your file name

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
/*********************Add column headings START**********************/
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'username')
            ->setCellValue('B1', 'city_name');

/*********************Add data entries START**********************/
//get_result_array_from_class**You can replace your sql code with this line.

$result = $get_report_clas->get_user_report();

//set variable for count table fields.
$num_row = 1;
foreach ($result as $value) {
  $user_name = $value['username'];
  $c_code = $value['city_name'];
  $num_row++;
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue('A'.$num_row, $user_name )
                ->setCellValue('B'.$num_row, $c_code );
}

/*********************Autoresize column width depending upon contents START**********************/
foreach(range('A','B') as $columnID) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($columnID)->setAutoSize(true);
}
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:B1')->getFont()->setBold(true);



//Make heading font bold
    /*********************Add color to heading START**********************/
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                ->getStyle('A1:B1')
                ->getFill()
                ->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)
                ->getStartColor()
                ->setARGB('99ff99');

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('userReport'); //give title to sheet
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=$filename.xls");
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```